# How to revert Ubuntu 13.10 icons

Tags: 13.10, icons

I installed an icon pack and wish to revert back to the original icon pack. How do you revert to the original pack?

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it from Ubuntu tweak tool.
install it from

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Then open ubuntu-tweak and there at Themes you can reset icons to original.

Answer (score 0):

install unity tweak tool .By using that you can revert to Ubuntu stack icons.
Open your terminal and type as

```
  sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

then open it , there you can change your icons to its defaults.

Answer (score 0):

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open terminal and run the below commands to reset icons,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme ''
sudo shutdown -r now
```

After restarted,you will revert back to original icons.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which desktop environment you are utilizing, you have several options.

(Some options are:)

Unity Tweak Tool (After Install, press the Super/Windows Key, and begin to type Unity Tweak Tool in the search bar. Once located, open the tool and under "Appearance" you'll see an option for Icons. Click there, and select the Icon Theme you wish you use.

> sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

Gnome Tweak Tool (After Installing, press the Super/Windows Key, and begin to type Gnome Tweak Tool in the search bar. Once located, open the tool, click "Appearance" and then select the Icon Theme you wish to use.)

> sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

Ubuntu Tweak (After Installing, press the Super/Windows Key, and begin to type Ubuntu, and the tool will present itself. Once open, you can click "Tweaks" > "Theme" and then select the Icon Theme you want to use.)

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak